# Self-referencing table Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called commitments where the primary key is `commit_no` and a self referencing column in called `commit_rollup_no`. My goal is to be able to pull back all the referenced tabled based on the highest `commit_no`.

**Example**

```
commit_no | commit_rollup_no
---------------------------
1           null
2           1
3           1
4           2
5           3
6           5
7           6
```

Desired Result:

for all commitments that rollup to commit_no 1

```
2,3,4,5,6,7
```

for all commitments that rollup to commit_no 2

```
4
```

for all commitments that rollup to commit_no 3

```
5,6,7
```

I was wondering how someone with more experiencing with self-referring tables might tackle this query. In some cases it might go 100 levels deep and the requirement is to get all the associated commitments back.

Comment: I have used SR Tables and I would simply use `SELECT commit_no FROM table WHERE commit_rollup_no = N`. What will you want the output to be?

Comment: To get the highest one, I would use `SELECT commit_no FROM table WHERE commit_rollup_no = null`.

Comment: Hey @PraveenKumar the desired output would be all the associated commitments.

Comment: Lemme try a fiddle for you.

Comment: Sql Server, Oracle, and Postgresql can do this via recursive CTE (which has been part of the ansi standard since 1999, so shame on MySql for not supporting this yet). MySql doesn't have CTEs, but it _might_ be able to use an ugly group_concat hack (which is _not_ part of the ansi sql standard)... but I'm not holding my breath in this case.

Comment: Hey @JoelCoehoorn, I attempted to accomplish a CTE with While loops but it's ugly and I was hopping someone might have a better method or even an example.

Comment: Thanks for trying @PraveenKumar, the answer you provided is where I'm stuck. I need to output to display all the associated commitments not just the first level. If the input commitment was 1 the output would be 2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`IDPAdmin`@`%` FUNCTION `CommitChildren`(ParentCommit INT) RETURNS varchar(1024) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children VARCHAR(1024);
DECLARE queue_length,front_id,pos INT;

SET rv = '';
SET queue = ParentCommit;
SET queue_length = 1;

WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
    IF queue_length = 1 THEN
    SET front_id = queue;
        SET queue = '';
    ELSE
         SET front_id = SUBSTR(queue,1,LOCATE(',',queue)-1);
    SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
    SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
    SET queue = q;
END IF;
    SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;

    SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
    FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(commit_no) qc
    FROM commitments WHERE commit_rollup_no = front_id) A;

    IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
        IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
            SET queue_length = 0;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
            SET rv = queue_children;
        ELSE
            SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
        END IF;
        IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
            SET queue = queue_children;
        ELSE
            SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
    END IF;
END WHILE;

RETURN rv;

END
```

Comment: Wow. How do you execute this? Eager to see a working fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work out for you?

```
SELECT `commit_no`,
       (SELECT Group_concat(`commit_no`)
        FROM   `commits` `c`
        WHERE  `c`.`commit_rollup_no` = `com`.`commit_no`) AS `SubCommits`
FROM   `commits` AS `com`
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/996e2/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE commits
    (`commit_no` int, `commit_rollup_no` int)
;

INSERT INTO commits
    (`commit_no`, `commit_rollup_no`)
VALUES
    (1, 0),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 1),
    (4, 2),
    (5, 3),
    (6, 5),
    (7, 6)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT `commit_no`, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`commit_no`) FROM `commits` `c` WHERE `c`.`commit_rollup_no` = `com`.`commit_no`) AS `SubCommits` FROM `commits` AS `com`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/996e2/2/0)**:

```
+-----------+------------+
| commit_no | SubCommits |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |        2,3 |
|         2 |          4 |
|         3 |          5 |
|         4 |     (null) |
|         5 |          6 |
|         6 |          7 |
|         7 |     (null) |
+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: This doesn't match the desired results from the question. The OP needs this to recurse. Because 2 is a subcommit for 1, the results for 1 also need to show 2's subcommits, and so on.

Comment: Hey @PraveenKumar, I'm able to get this far with a inner join but I need to see the Hierarchical association. Example, input 1 output: 2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: @chasecabrera I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Oh, are you looking for a tree like structure?